# JSON to Python3 POST (shipcloud API)

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I want to create a shipment in Shipcloud via API-POST. As described in the docs https://developers.shipcloud.io/reference/shipments_request_schema.html
I am using the requests module for Python3. And i am trying to convert this json to a python because iam getting "NameError: name 'true' is not defined". I found a similar example on github [Github example vinothzeabalane](https://github.com/vinothzeabalane/shipcloud/commit/5d2becbd34323147bf53424b8550d604f2877a8b) but this one is for getting the addresses.
Why doesnt this work?

```
import requests
import json
from shipcloud_apikey import bk_sandbox_apikey

datas = {

  {
  "to": {
      "company": "Receiver Inc.",
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "street": "Beispielstrasse",
      "street_no": "42",
      "city": "Musterhausen",
      "zip_code": "22100",
      "country": "DE"
  },
  "package": {
      "weight": 15,
      "length": 30,
      "width": 30,
      "height": 30,
      "type": "parcel"
  },
  "carrier": "dpd",
  "service": "standard",
  "reference_number": "ref123456",
  "notification_email": "john.doe@company.com",
  "create_shipping_label": true
  }
}

pydata = json.load(datas)


requests.post('https://api.shipcloud.io/v1/shipments', auth=('bk_sandbox_apikey', ''), data = pydata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple issues here:

1) You have one extra set of brackets `{}` surrounding the dictionary that should not be there (I'm guessing this happen when copying the code here). So the data should be:

```
datas = {
  "to": {
      "company": "Receiver Inc.",
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "street": "Beispielstrasse",
      "street_no": "42",
      "city": "Musterhausen",
      "zip_code": "22100",
      "country": "DE"
  },
  "package": {
      "weight": 15,
      "length": 30,
      "width": 30,
      "height": 30,
      "type": "parcel"
  },
  "carrier": "dpd",
  "service": "standard",
  "reference_number": "ref123456",
  "notification_email": "john.doe@company.com",
  "create_shipping_label": true
}
```

2) [json.load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) takes a filehandle-type variable to return a dictionary, basically, it would create the dictionary that you are already creating by hand.

3) It is right, `true` is expected to be a variable in this scenario and, as it is not defined, it raises an error. Thus, I don't think you actually need the [json.load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load), but the solution, I hope it helps, would be to first change `true` to the actual data variable, so:

```
"create_shipping_label": True
```

And then use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to make the dictionary into a string and [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to make the string back into a dictionary, such as:

```
pydata = json.loads(json.dumps(datas))
```

Again, I don't think you might need that, but at least doing this one makes sure the data works properly with the json library.

Comment: You are right. I do not need to convert it into valid python code.  The requests-module can handle it when i write the whole json array in a single line. The curly braces seem to be okay. Also i cloud leave the json-true value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://api.shipcloud.io/v1/shipments', auth=(bk_sandbox_apikey, ''), data='{"to": {"company": "nocompany","first_name": "lalaal","last_name": "asdasd","street": "Musterstrasse","street_no": "71","city": "Musterhausen","zip_code": "73324","country": "DE"},"package": {"weight": 7,"length": 10,"width": 10,"height": 10,"type": "parcel"},"carrier": "dpd","service": "standard","reference_number": "TESTSENDUNG BK2","notification_email": "test@testing.de","create_shipping_label": true}')
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

for print(r) i get back the status code 200 which means it worked just fine.
r.text throws back the shipcloud id and tracking url.